Loading PricebookEntry records via Bulk v2 API using Postman
Trying to get a bulk api 2 job working to upsert records for the PricebookEntry object in Salesforce CPQ. The following is the contents of csv file.
ITEM_id__c,Pricebook2.ITEM_id__c,IsActive,UnitPrice,Product2.ITEM_id__c
"70711_224827","203","true","5.99","224827"

The fields & Relationships of the PricebookEntry table:
Field Label           Field Name        Data Type                  Indexed
===========================================================================
Active                IsActive          Checkbox                   False    
Created By            CreatedById       Lookup(User)               False    
Last Modified By      LastModifiedById  Lookup(User)               False    
List Price            UnitPrice         Currency(16, 2)            False    
ITEM id               ITEM_id__c        Text(255) (External ID)    True 
Price Book            Pricebook2Id      Lookup(Price Book)         True 
Product               Product2Id        Lookup(Product)            True 
Product Code          ProductCode       Text(255)                  False    
Use Standard Price    UseStandardPrice  Checkbox

Body of the create job API:
{
    "object" : "PricebookEntry",
    "externalIdFieldName" : "ITEM_id__c",
    "contentType" : "CSV",
    "operation" : "upsert",
    "lineEnding" : "CRLF"
}

And here is  the response of the job status call:
{
    "id": "750VA000003WmB5YAK",
    "operation": "upsert",
    "object": "PricebookEntry",
    "createdById": "0058K000003dFCIQA2",
    "createdDate": "2024-05-15T22:17:59.000+0000",
    "systemModstamp": "2024-05-15T22:18:16.000+0000",
    "state": "Failed",
    "externalIdFieldName": "ITEM_id__c",
    "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "apiVersion": 58.0,
    "jobType": "V2Ingest",
    "lineEnding": "CRLF",
    "columnDelimiter": "COMMA",
    "numberRecordsProcessed": 0,
    "numberRecordsFailed": 0,
    "retries": 0,
    "totalProcessingTime": 0,
    "apiActiveProcessingTime": 0,
    "apexProcessingTime": 0,
    "errorMessage": "InvalidBatch : Field name not found : ----------------------------282877410032705839969190"
}

Not sure what the large numeric string of "282877410032705839969190" means. It changes with every try.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

How did you come up with the 1st (header) row of your CSV file?

It's based on the fields of the pricebookentry table - edited and added above.

The fields in your header row do not exactly match PricebookEntry table snapshot above. Anyway, you should read the docs and do a search of other Q&As here, Most common root causes: a field name mismatch or a permission issue.

The csv file shown above is using the field name of the parent table for the lookup fields. Already tried the pricebookentry field names themselves, but no luck. I agree it's a permissions issue somewhere. The API call uses client credentials for token request. I've already granted full access for the corresponding connected app, but no difference yet.

Finally figured it out. While trying different users with the connected app to work on different tables, all got the same error. Then I started looking into the details of API calls in Postman. It turned out that it's related to how you upload the csv file. Salesforce refuses to work if you choose "form-data" and specify a file name in there. It worked when I selected "binary".
